# In-App purchases from Google Play

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-developer-api, in-app-subscription

We have a app in google play that a user subscribes to.  We need to get a list of all subscribers along with their billing history to reconcile our payment records.  Is there a way to get an export of this information from Google Play?  I don't see any documentation for a batch download/report/api call.  I only see that you can search google play with a user's orderid and then you have to manually view their billing history.

We can get this info from iTunes but not google that I can see.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get some of this information from the earnings reports. Information on getting these, including programmatically from Google Cloud [is here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870). See the "Earnings Reports" section.

Comment: Thanks!  I think this is just what we need.

Comment: We also send our customer id and it is in the response we get back from Google Play on receipt verification as ""developerPayload".  I was hoping this would be included in the report but it's not.  This would help us link to all of the records in our db for that user.  Is there a way to get that into the report? or is there another way to get it?

Comment: Also in the response there is a "kind" element that returns always 
 "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase" but its not the title of the product the user subscribed to.  We have a monthly subscription and an annual subscription.  How do I get which product they selected (monthly or annual)?